# Get canonical value of relative path from bash script

Tags: bash

I've been using a command like the following to get the directory of a particular script when it is executed, regardless of where it was executed from:

```
MYDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
```

What would be the similar one liner to get the canonical path for the directory that is two parents above the script directory? I have tried things like:

```
MYDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0/../..))
MYDIR=$(readlink -f $(dirname $(readlink -f $0)/../..))
```

I'm not a bash guru, as you can tell. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give `/../..` to the last `readlink`, not to `dirname`:

```
$(readlink -f "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")/../..")
```

Your script causes `dirname path/to/script/../..` to be executed, outputting "`path/to/script/..`", which `readlink` refuses to canonicalize because constructs such as `file/..` are invalid in Linux and the `-f` option requires all components to exist. (`readlink -m` would work, since it does not check for existence of any path components.)

Answer (score 4):

For those who don't have readlink (like me on git bash)

```
#!/bin/bash

function canonicalPath
{
    local path="$1" ; shift
    if [ -d "$path" ]
    then
        echo "$(cd "$path" ; pwd)"
    else
        local b=$(basename "$path")
        local p=$(dirname "$path")
        echo "$(cd "$p" ; pwd)/$b"
    fi
}

# usage example
mycanonicalpath=$(canonicalPath "$myrelativepath")
```

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to tie this into an answer to the question. It's a neat wrapper for turning `pwd` into something greater, though. Very unixy =)